# Is it theoretically possible to create an aircraft like this?

Tags: aircraft-design

I was browsing through some funny airplane pictures when I came across this. An airplane with the engines replaced with the cockpit and the cockpit replaced with a huge turbofan.

I was intrigued by this idea, but then it also brought up the question: Is it theoretically possible to create an aircraft like this and be possible for the aircraft to take flight? (as in fly in the air for prolonged time)

[image: Funny Airplane]
Source: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSJcCf3Crdk)

Comment: yes but it wouldnt fly for long LMAO

Comment: Given enought thrust, anything can fly

Comment: But the question is, is there enough thrust in this case?

Comment: Like the  [CAPRONI-STIPA](https://www.italianways.com/the-caproni-stipa/)

Comment: Mig 21 isn't far away from this in concept: pilot sitting on top of a big engine with payload under the wings.

Comment: @user3528438: MiG-15 & 17 even more so. ttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikoyan-Gurevich_MiG-15 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikoyan-Gurevich_MiG-17  Or the US-built F-86 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_F-86_Sabre

Comment: I think it is possible see the aerodyne of alexander lippish...i dont know if he fly

Comment: Look like the clip-air

Comment: Do you mean a [twin fuselage](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Baircraft-design%5D+twin+fuselage) with one [large engine](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/search?q=large+engine)?

Comment: @SSumner "We need more thrust!" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r6wsDO-Ik4

Comment: Unless you show us what the back end of the plane looks like, this question is unanswerable.  A big fan trying to cram air into the front of the fuselage leads to no thrust if the air (including the portion that is expanded after combustion) has nowhere to exit.  Plus it is unclear if or how the big round yellow thing is attached to the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea has been tried. [This WWII aircraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blohm_%26_Voss_BV_141) is built around the idea very much like yours: engine in the main fuselage, pilots/passengers in the nacelle.

It must be reasons to choose this design. The design requirements were:

- One engine.
- Crew one or two
- Best possible view into to all sides
  (reconnaissance aircraft).

For the passenger aircraft as pictured it is probably just not optimal.

[image]

Comment: This aircraft looks like the [boomerang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutan_Boomerang)

Answer (score 1):

There have been several planes generally similar to this, some quite successful. Early examples were the Italian [Savoia-Marchetti S.55](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savoia-Marchetti_S.55) and [S.66](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savoia-Marchetti_S.66) twin-hulled flying boats with a row of engines above the hulls and these were the most numerous.
[image: Aeroflot Savoia-Marchetti S.55P]

[image: Savoia-Marchetti S.66 3-view Drawing]

They were the only ones to carry passengers on either side.

The most famous is surely the German WWII Heinkel He 111Z glider tug. It comprised two He 111 twin-engined bombers joined by a straight centre section with a fifth engine in the middle.
[image: Heinkel He 111Z glider tug]

The French [Fouga CM.88 Gemeaux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fouga_CM.88_Gemeaux) engine-test aircraft had twin fuselages and for engine testing its original engines were replaced by a single central engine. It flight-tested several jet and turboprop engines in this way and is probably the only one to have flown with a single central jet, indeed any jet.
[image: Fouga CM.88 Gemeaux]

The Slovenian [Pipistrel Taurus G4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipistrel_Taurus) is a more recent engine development platform for electric-powered aircraft. A few others have flown, or tried to, but proved useless.
[image: Pipistrel Taurus G4]

Answer (score -2):

There inst a jet engine that size, and this is very unfathomable when it comes to reliability, safety, and efficiency. But, if you are asking if we can design a plane with the power plant as the main fuselage/airframe, then probably yes, a very bad one.

Comment: The GE9X nacelle is only 10cm smaller than the B737 fuselage...

Comment: The problem with very large turbofans is that the fans are difficult to scale. To avoid sonic shockwaves and noise they must turn slowly so that the tips stay subsonic, so they have to be geared down off the turbine. Also making the blades strong enough to resists birdstrike and similar gets harder. Nevertheless Rolls-Royce do now have one under development, called the Ultrafan.